# Como acceder al valor de un item en un Form Array en Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios, validación

Buen dia

Podrian ayudarme a saber como acceder al valor de un item en especifico dentro de un Form Array en Angular 8. No comprendo bien como hacerlo.

Tengo esta informacion dentro del Form Array, quiero poder obtener el valor tanto de la fecha de inicio como la de fin para poder crear una validacion en la que la fecha fin no pueda ser menor que la fecha inicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo TS tengo mi form array asi:

```
 get planActividades(): FormArray {
        console.log("FORM ARRAY PLAN",<FormArray>this.contratoForm.get('planActividades').value)
        return <FormArray>this.contratoForm.get('planActividades'); 
    }
```

estoy intentando acceder al valor de fecha inicio A asi:

```
getFechaInicioA() {

        let a = this.contratoForm.get('planActividades.fechaInicioA').value
        console.log("Fecha Inicio",a)
}
```

pero me sale el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de distintas formas:

```
getFechaInicioA() {
    let a = this.contratoForm.get('planActividades').controls[0].value.fechaInicioA
    let b = this.contratoForm.get('planActividades').value[0].fechaInicioA

    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
}
```

Dejo el ejemplo funcional: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ftpbu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Form Array es una matriz y tienes que acceder los controles por el indice. Para eso existe el método [at](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at).

```
const actividades = this.contratoForm.get('planActividades') as FormArray;
const actividad = actividades.at(0);
console.log(actividad.value);
```